# Why does it appear like it is snowing in my animation?

Tags: animation, particles, physics, light

I created a simple animation where I am circling around a chair in a room. For some reason, as I was key framing the camera, I noticed that at around 60 frames, this weird snow-like particle stuff started falling and it happens for about 40 frames. I have no idea what is happening or how to make it go away. I didn't hit anything accidentally to my knowledge. Anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? [image: Rendered at about 70 frames in]
[image]

Comment: Those sure look like emitter-style particles. Is it possible you created a particle system by chance?

Comment: Looks like your ceiling is a particle system. Check all your scene layers and inspect them if you accidentlay didn't enable it for some object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that "snow" is caused by a particle system. Like you can see at the image you need to turn of HALO in that particle system that created the particles.

So find that particle system and turn of HALO

[image]